# Is this the right way to count in multithreads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to get all counts from WorkerThread class after the 5 threads finished. Does the Counter work the way as expected? Thanks. In the WorkerThread constructor, it seems each counter becomes one variable of each thread, not shared among the 5 threads.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread(String.valueOf(i), counter);
            executor.execute(worker);
          }
        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Total Count: " + counter.value());
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }

}

class Counter{
    private AtomicInteger count;

    public Counter(){
        count = new AtomicInteger();
    }

    public int increment(){
        return count.incrementAndGet();
    }

    public int value(){
        return count.get();
    }
}

class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

    private String command;
    private Counter c;

    public WorkerThread(String s, Counter c){
        this.command=s;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){         
            c.increment();
        }
        processCommand();       
    }

    private void processCommand() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.command;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is the issue?

Comment: You should not `e.printStackTrace()` an `InterruptionException`. At the very least you should `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`. Also, for readability, you could use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5L);`.

Comment: You might want to glance over this [Java Reference Variables](http://way2java.com/oops-concepts/reference-variables-anonymous-objects/) tutorial; it will give you insight into what `this.c = c` is actually doing.

Comment: The javadoc for [`shutdown`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) says it does **not** wait for threads to terminate.

Comment: I run the program multiple times, and it seems the results are not always right. Sometimes is 30, and sometimes is 24. Should always be 30?

Comment: @CongminMin no, you can't tell when the `for` loop in the threads will start running relative to the main thread.  Is 30 the correct result?  If not, what result were you expecting to see and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronization seems correct to me. If counting is your only task, you could skip the Counter class and directly use AtomicInteger to remove complexity. (Keep it if you want to realize more complex tasks which require a proper synchronized shared state object).

Don't call your worker class "Thread". It is not a thread, it is a task that is executed by a thread.

Last but not least, there's something wrong with your shutdown-code. Note that shutdown does not block but return immediately. So you're evaluating your counter too early.

The following code fixes all of this issues:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Worker(counter));
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        if (!executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            // executor does not shut down.
            // try executor.shutdownNow() etc.
        }

        System.out.println("Total Count: " + counter.get());
    }
}

class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicInteger counter;

    public Worker(AtomicInteger counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void run() {
        // do something
        counter.incrementAndGet();
        // do something else
    }
}
```

For more information about how to correctly shutdown an `ExecutorService`, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html, section 'Usage Examples'.

Comment: While switching to an `AtomicInteger` directly may simplify the code in this specific example, I would definitely not recommend that as a general approach. Having a `Counter` class allows you to add other functionality, e.g. callbacks and progress notifications when the value changes and the ability to wait until the counter hits a certain value (and the ability to switch to other implementations depending on the requirements, e.g. a `Semaphore` or a `CountDownLatch`, etc.). An `AtomicInteger` alone doesn't really have much in terms of functionality.

Comment: I agree. But in that specific example, the Counter class makes the code much more complex and distracts from the main question about synchronization. Nevertheless, I'll update my answer.